# What the RESTFul API for GetList of Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am looking for the `SharePoint OnLine RESTFul API` try to get all lists of specified `Site`.

Let's say the default Site of Site Collection in my Office 365 SharePoint OnLine trial.
The Site Collection is `https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/`.

I just found a sample code for the managed `Server Class Libary` for `SharePoint 2013`.

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost/sites/sitecollection"))
 {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("sitecollection/subsite"))
    {
       string listUrl = "/sites/sitecollection/subsite/Lists/Announcements";
       SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
       Console.WriteLine("List URL: {0}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
    }
 }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Is there any RESTFul for it? If could give me some code sample. It will be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for a C# example, the below example demonstrates how to retrieve all lists via [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (you could also utilize [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose)

Endpoint: `/_api/web/lists`

## How to retrieve lists using SharePoint REST

```
public static JToken GetLists(Uri webUri,ICredentials credentials)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");
        var endpointUri = new Uri(webUri, "/_api/web/lists/");
        var result = client.DownloadString(endpointUri);
        var t = JToken.Parse(result);
        return t["d"]["results"];
    }
}
```

> Dependency: [Json.NET library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usage

The example demonstrates how to print lists titles in SPO site:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var webUri = new Uri("https://contoso.sharepoint.com");
      const string userName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
      const string password = "password";
      var securePassword = new SecureString();
      foreach (var c in password)
      {
          securePassword.AppendChar(c);
      }
      var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

      var lists = GetLists(webUri,credentials);
      //print List title
      foreach (var list in lists)
      {
            Console.WriteLine(list["Title"]);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep you can get this from /_api/web/lists. You can try it out in a browser using https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists. There are loads of code samples on the internet but best place to start is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx#bk_ListCollection)

Comment: +1 Right , I can see the XML content in my browser. But Why all these MSDN samples are Javascript ? Is there any C# version for them ? Thanks.

Comment: MS is moving towards the App model. I think if you are not using JavaScript in SharePoint now you will be fairly soon. There are still plenty of REST samples for C# about but you might want to decide why you would use REST over CSOM.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Bunzab's answer, but here is an [MSDN example of exactly what you're asking about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx) (in C#):

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest =
  (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://<site url>/_api/web/lists");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
// You don't need the following line if you're doing this from within an App Web
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse =
  (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

Get your google going! =)